# Clone DOM elements and IDs

Tags: javascript, dom, clonenode

Am I missing something, but when you clone an existing DOM element using 'cloneNode', it produces a copy of the existing element with the exact same attributes.  If passed 'true' this includes the children, but what use is this because the ID attribute if declared is the same for the clones.

Changing the ID's isn't difficult, but my question is, is there a built in method of producing a copy of an element and its children without producing something that will conflict with existing elements in the DOM?

Comment: There's not, you've to change/remove a cloned id manually.

Comment: Thank you, thats as I thought.